# How to combine query strings in google drive API python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am using some python code to list all the files in a folder. I also do not want deleted or trashed files to be listed. I know both queries for this but I am unsure about how to combine them

`response = service.files().list(q = "'"+str(folderId)+"' in parents").execute()`

Is my current method, `folderId` being the folder that will have its files listed.

I know that the queries for "search in folder" and "not deleted" are:

`"'<folderid>' in parents"`

`"trashed = false"`

I have tried combining with `;` `,` and `+` and cannot find the correct way to combine them online anywhere else. I'm sure it's simple and someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please make a simplistic copy of your code that gives the same error?

Comment: `query = "'" + str(folderId) + "' in parents" # '1234abc' in parents`
`response = service.files().list(q = query).execute()`

not really sure exactly what you mean, is this simple enough?

Comment: What I meant was could you provide me with a *functioning* code that gives you the same error.

Comment: `response = service.files().list(q = "'"+str(folderId)+"' in parents, trashed=false").execute()` This?

Comment: How about modifying from `"'"+str(folderId)+"' in parents, trashed=false"` to `"'"+str(folderId)+"' in parents and trashed=false"` using `and` instead of `,`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need ***and*** operator to combine multiple filters in a query string

Try this

```
query = "parents in '%s' and trashed = false" % folderId
response = service.files().list(q = query).execute()
```